# What does it mean to vary holomorphically?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It is well known that for a smooth complex projective variety the subspaces $H^{p,q}$ do not vary holomorphically with families. What does it mean to vary holomorphically with families? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The de Rham cohomology (in some fixed degree) of the fibres of the family form the fibres of a holomorphic vector bundle over the base.  However, the $(p,q)$-decompositions of the fibres do not glue to give a decomposition of this vector bundle into a direct sum of holomorphic subbundles (although the $h_{p,q}$'s, i.e. the dimensions of the various $(p,q)$ pieces, are constant over the family, assuming the base is connected).

Comment: I see, the $F^p$'s give such a decomposition that's why one says that they vary holomorphically, make sense. Thanks.